# I don't understand the error occured in my script, please help me

Tags: python

I was working on this question on LeetCode, here's the link: https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/linked-list/209/singly-linked-list/1290/. I have to design an object MyLinkedList, here is my code:

```
class Node(object):
    
    def __init__(self, val, next):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None # next : Node

class MyLinkedList(object):
    
    def __init__(self, head):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here.
        """
        self.head = Node(None, None) # head : Node

    def get(self, index):
        """
        Get the value of the index-th node in the linked list. If the index is invalid, return -1.
        :type index: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if index < 0:
            return -1
        else:
            current = self.head
            count = 0
            while current != None:
                if index == count:
                    return current.val
                current = current.next
                count += 1
            return -1

    def addAtHead(self, val):
        """
        Add a node of value val before the first element of the linked list. After the insertion, the new node will be the first node of the linked list.
        :type val: int
        :rtype: None
        """
        New = Node(val, None)
        New.next = self.head
        self.head = New

    def addAtTail(self, val):
        """
        Append a node of value val to the last element of the linked list.
        :type val: int
        :rtype: None
        """
        current = self.head
        while current.next != None:
            current = current.next
        New = Node(val, None)
        current.next = New
        
    def addAtIndex(self, index, val):
        """
        Add a node of value val before the index-th node in the linked list. If index equals to the length of linked list, the node will be appended to the end of linked list. If index is greater than the length, the node will not be inserted.
        :type index: int
        :type val: int
        :rtype: None
        """
        if index == 0:
            self.addAtHead(val)
        else:
            New = Node(val, None)
            current = self.head
            count = 0
            while current != None:
                prev = current
                current = current.next
                count += 1
                if count == index:
                    prev.next = New
                    New.next = current
                    return
            
    def deleteAtIndex(self, index):
        """
        Delete the index-th node in the linked list, if the index is valid.
        :type index: int
        :rtype: None
        """
        if index == 0:
            self.head = self.head.next
        else:
            current = self.head
            count = 0
            while current != None:
                prev = current
                current = current.next
                count += 1
                if count == index:
                    prev.next = current.next
                    return

# Your MyLinkedList object will be instantiated and called as such:
# obj = MyLinkedList()
# param_1 = obj.get(index)
# obj.addAtHead(val)
# obj.addAtTail(val)
# obj.addAtIndex(index,val)
# obj.deleteAtIndex(index)
```

I try running my code and saw this error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
    obj = MyLinkedList()
Line 171 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 185 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Can someone help me fix this error, I would be very grateful

Comment: In addition, this is the input: ["MyLinkedList","addAtHead","addAtTail","addAtIndex","get","deleteAtIndex","get"]
[[],[1],[3],[1,2],[1],[1],[1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    def __init__(self, head):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here.
        """
        self.head = Node(None, None) # head : Node
```

to this:

```
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize your data structure here.
        """
        self.head = Node(None, None)
```

Since the constructor doesn't use the value of `head` it takes as a parameter, there's no reason to ask for it in the first place.